# probabilty mass function of random variables

Tags: probability

The random variables X and Y have a joint probability mass function given by the table below:

[image]

1. Find the probability mass function of Z = X+Y. What is P(Z=4)?
2. Find E(Z).

I've tried to do the following but it is incorrect. Please help

$$\begin{align}
P(z=4) & = p(x=1, y=3) + p(x=2, y=2) + p(x=3, y=1)
       \\[2ex] & = (0.05 + 0.01 +0.01 + 0.01)(0.1 + 0.2 + 0.04) 
        \\[0ex] &  + (0.15 + 0.25 + 0.20 + 0.05)(0.01 + 0.25 + 0.03)
        \\[0ex] &  + (0.01 + 0.03 + 0.04 + 0.01)(0.05 + 0.15 + 0.01)
       \\[2ex] & = 0.26(0.34) + 0.65(0.38) + 0.09(0.21)
       \\[2ex] & = 0.3543
\end{align}$$

Comment: We have $\Pr(Z=4)=\Pr(X=1,Y=3)+\Pr(X=2,Y=2)+\Pr(X=3,Y=1)=0.10+0.25+0.01=0.36$. Do a similar calculation for $\Pr(Z=2)$, $\Pr(Z=3)$, and so on up to $\Pr(Z=7)$. That will give you the distribution of $Z$, from which you can find the expectation in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\mathsf P(x=1, y=3) = 0.10\;$, the single value in both the first row and third column.

It is *not* equal to: $\mathsf P(x=1)\times \mathsf P(y=3)\;$.   Don't sum values in a column and multiply by the sum of values in a row, as that won't give the right result.

The **product rule** *of independent events* can only be used when the events are *independent*.   Clearly, they are not such.